# Can $\mathrm{d}x$ be thought of as a derivative and differentiation or it's just a small change in $x$ and nothing more?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, infinitesimals

The $\mathrm{d}x$ appears on integrals. I saw conflicting views regarding it. People sometimes write it does have a connection to differentiation and derivatives. Does it or does it not?

Comment: "Conflicting views"

Comment: The simple answer to _that_ concern is that they are _not conflicting_. You get a different answer depending on whether you ask an algebraist, a differential geometer, a physicist, or a probability theorist, sure. But they do not conflict, any more than one divided by two is either $\frac12$ or $0.5$, and that's not conflictive. The different answers convey different ways of thinking, but the resulting calculations will give the same answer. So yes, it does or does not have a connection to derivatives, and it's fine like that.

Comment: in "TGIF", does the G stand for "Goodness" or "God"? Depends who's saying it, doesn't it?

Comment: Arthur What the heck ? I am talking about people writing its related to differentiation while other who deny it.

Comment: That's probably because they're too stuck in their own interpretation to see that other interpretations are also true.

Comment: It is used in expressing **differential equations,** @bilanush.  Equations of the sort (a simple example): $\frac {dy}{dx} \cdot \frac 1{y} = (3x^2-2) \iff \frac {dy}{y} = (3x^2-2)dx$.  This is solved by integrating the LHS with respect to y, and the RHS with respect to $x$.  And so we obtain: $$\ln|y| = x^3-2x + c$$ or $$y= \exp(x^3-2x +C) = C\exp(x^3-2x)$$

Answer (score 1):

$dx$ means $\Delta{x}$, or an infinitesimal change in $x$. The $\frac{d}{dx}$ in derivatives is simply a mathematical operator that you apply to a function; it comes from $\frac{\Delta{y}}{\Delta{x}}$ = $\frac{\Delta}{\Delta x}y=\frac{d}{dx}y$.

Comment: Agree. But some people do appear to affiliate it with "differentiation" , "integration" what do they mean?

Comment: For differentiation, we want the slope of the secant line to approximate the slope of the tangent line, so we want the change in $x$ and $y$ to become as small as possible. $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is used to represent this. For integrals, we are summing up rectangles under the curve (Riemann sum) as the width ($dx$) of these rectangles approaches $0$. So either way $dx$ means an infinitely small change in $x$.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the context in which $dx$ appears.

If $x$ is a function of $t$, then $$dx=x'(t)dt$$ involves derivative.

If $dx$ appears in an integral, it simply means  integrate with respect to $x$.

If it appears as a denominator such as $\frac {df}{dx}$ it mean differentiate with respect to $x$

If it is standing by itself it means an increment in $x$